# How will hide label using div in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want hide a label according to a dropdown button. I am using a div with JavaScript. My code is:

```
<div id="ime" name="ime">
    <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
        <label>
            <nobr>IEMI No</nobr>
        </label>
    </h3>
</div>
```

For hiding  through JavaScript,which  I am using:

```
ime.style.display='none';
document.getElementById("ime").style.display='none';
document.getElementsByName("ime").style.display='none';
```

But this code is not working.

Comment: `document.getElementById("ime").style.display='none';` should work. where you put this code. this should execute after `DOM` is ready

Comment: @user633856 :  have tried code posted by me???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page load id to this div is not assigned that's way it is not working. Use this after body tag at the end of page.

write this way

```
<html>
<body>
.
.
.
.
.
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         document.getElementById('ime').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you just use `document.getElementById("ime").style.display='none';` without the other two lines (which will not work)?

I expect that the first line will throw an error, because `ime` is not defined, which will prevent execution of the next two lines.

The third line will not work, because it returns an array of objects, which individually have a style attribute, but not together...

```
// this would work on the first `ime` tag
document.getElementsByName("ime")[0].style.display='none';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work

```
document.getElementById("ime").style.display='none';
```